# Could you please explain this statement by providing an implementation of the design pattern it alludes to?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

The [Managed Threading Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page states:

*Avoid providing static methods that alter static state. In common server scenarios, static state is shared across requests, which means multiple threads can execute that code at the same time. This opens up the possibility of threading bugs. **Consider using a design pattern that encapsulates data into instances that are not shared across requests.** Furthermore, if static data are synchronized, calls between static methods that alter state can result in deadlocks or redundant synchronization, adversely affecting performance.*

I understand all the rest except for the one sentence that is in bold.

How would you do this without essentially changing the field from a static one to an instance one? Isn't that saying, "In a server scenario, avoid using static class-level members as much as you can?"

If it isn't, could you please provide an implementation of the design pattern it is alluding to?

Comment: Hmmm, basically is telling you to not use static members, that's all, create new instances for each request to isolate all the data for the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How would you do this without essentially changing the field from a static one to an instance one?

No one can possibly answer this question without knowing *why you thought that putting something in a static field was a good idea in the first place*.

> Isn't that saying, "In a server scenario, avoid using static class-level members as much as you can?"

No.  To be clear, **that is a good idea**. But that's not what this sentence is trying to communicate. It is saying *if you have a problem that you think could be solved by making a static method that modifies static state, then maybe you should consider finding some other way to solve the problem*.

> If it isn't, could you please provide an implementation of the design pattern it is alluding to?

Design patterns exist to solve problems. **You haven't said what problem you're solving**, so it's impossible to recommend a pattern.

Look, suppose you're planning on constructing a building on sand, and I tell you that only fools build on sand, and you then say OK, give me a design for a building that still meets my needs, but *not built on sand*.  **I don't know what your needs are** and I don't know why you thought that building on sand was a good idea in the first place, so no, I can't do that.  But that does not change the fact that *only fools build on sand*.

Are you thinking of modifying static state in a multithreaded server scenario?  **That's a really foolish thing to do**.  Find another way to do whatever you want to do.  How?  I haven't the faintest idea; I don't know what you're trying to do. But that doesn't change the fact that you're unlikely to be successful by modifying static state on a multithreaded server.

Comment: *Are you thinking of modifying static state in a multithreaded server scenario? That's a really foolish thing to do* hmm, why? I don't see any problem on having static members modified by multiple threads while you know what you do and use a good locking mechanism, encapsulating (per example) a variable with a property and using a lock will guarantee it's consistency, any other problem beyond that?

Comment: @Gusman: the original quote mentions things like "threading bugs", "deadlocks", and performance issues due to synchronization.  These are some of the reasons to avoid altering static state in a multithreaded scenario. Using locks properly can avoid some of those problems, but using locks properly can be very hard.  And solving the problems that might arise can be very, very hard.  I think the advice is suggesting to take a path that avoids these problems by design.

Comment: @Gusman: You know of a *good* locking mechanism?  I only know of `lock`, which is a *horrid* locking mechanism.

Comment: Ok, so as I understand, its *safer* to use instances as they're isolated, but using static members *carefully* is also ok, right? I'm asking because I try to use as much as I can static members and never had a problem (I have a lot of care with deadlocks and synchronization) so if there is really any potential problem beyond these I would like to know.

Comment: @EricLippert well, you have lock, mutexes, Interlocked.XXXX, semahpores and so on (I should said synchronization mechanism than locking mechanisms, that's true). Why lock is horrid?

Comment: @Gusman: Locks are noncomposable. A *composable* system is one where we can reason about the correctness of the system by reasoning about the correctness of its parts. We have a method F, we determine that it gives correct outputs for correct inputs. We have a method G, we do the same.  We define a method `X H(X x) { return F(G(x)); }` and *we know that `H` is correct*.  That is *not at all true* of code that uses locks.

Comment: @EricLippert hmmm, very dense comment in very small lines :) I need to digest that to fully understand it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Gusman: Leaving threading issues aside, there are plenty of reasons to avoid modifying static state on servers, starting with: doing so means that you have tied your *correctness* to your *isolation strategy*.  Once you rely on static state having a particular behaviour, you can no longer decide to change isolation of computations to machine / process / appdomain boundaries without risking a break.

Comment: @Gusman: Just do a web search for "locks are not composable" and you will find a great many articles on this subject.

Comment: @EricLippert Yep, you're right, there are a lot!, starting to read it NOW! thanks again.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you for a clarification of the documentation. You've articulated what I could have in the original question and thereby confirmed what I thought it meant, no doubt, with plenty of condescension, to which you're entitled. :-)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: No condescension is intended or implied.

Comment: @EricLippert My profuse apologies, in which case. Thanks much for your time and help.